# Programmatically adding Write permissions to files in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my WPF MVVM application,I have a XML file to modify.
It is successfully working In Visual Studio.
But It showing error, while running the installed application.
How can i set the Permissions Through code..

me used this code ,

```
// current security settings.
FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(FilePath);

// Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
string rr = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name,
            FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));


// Set the new access settings.
File.SetAccessControl(FilePath, fSecurity);
```

Still cant solve the Problem...,

Thanks in advance..

see the exception...

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an
>   unauthorized operation.    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType type,
>   String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation,
>   SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl,
>   GenericAcl dacl)    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String
>   name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object
>   exceptionContext)    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String
>   name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext) 
>   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String
>   name, AccessControlSections includeSections)    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String
>   fullPath)    at System.IO.File.SetAccessControl(String path,
>   FileSecurity fileSecurity)

Answer (score 0):

To set permissions mostly it requires power user rights(assuming your are running windows 7).

To verify above, launch the Visual studio as "Run as Administrator" and debug the your code.

What is exact exception message?

Here is working example: It sets full permissions for user group EveryOne

```
private static void WriteAcl ( string filename ) 
        { 
            //Set security for EveryOne Group
            SecurityIdentifier sid =new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
            IdentityReference userIdentity =sid.Translate (typeof(NTAccount));           

            var AccessRule_AllowEveryOne = new FileSystemAccessRule ( userIdentity, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow );
            var securityDescriptor = new FileSecurity ();
            securityDescriptor.SetAccessRule ( AccessRule_AllowEveryOne );            
            File.SetAccessControl ( filename, securityDescriptor ); 
        }
```

This code works only if User Account Settings are set to Never notify. Looks its turned on at your computer?

A workaround is to launch your application as power user using Application Manifest.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: Is it the right way to change the UAS for an application Installation? Me getting the same exception without doing this..

Comment: Definitely with UAC on and running application with standard user will throw exception. You can assign permissions manually or automate using above code and forcing application to be launched with admin rights using application manifest. Regarding is it right or not, depends on situations and choices. My end user is not enough technical to setup the rights... i will prefer above way.

Comment: "application to be launched with admin rights using application manifest".Could you please give an example?

Comment: @Needo Thank you. You rock! You have solved a problem I had in a home app which I've been mulling over for ages. Now I need to go look at all those security classes an understand what they are doing. Cheers!