# how to write a file if user has non write permission

Tags: wpf, file, c#-4.0, permissions

Hi i have a application that creat/write a Logfile  (later it will write a ErrorLog)
but at the moment i stick in to the permission problem because if the user havn't the right to creat a File in the Folder where my app is it throws an exeption

now my question how do i get indipendent (from the user) creating and writing rights for this app

i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006523/programmatically-adding-write-permissions-to-files-in-wpf) but it doesn't help because the client won't be able to give that permissions
(they are not authorized) but i need that right for my app

your help will appreciated

Comment: Will your error log file be user specific? If different users run the app on the same computer will you have different logs? Or rather can you have? In that case you can create this log in teh User's app data folder, all users will have permissions to their own AppData folders.

Comment: It's a common conception (I would even say, a *best practice*) to have the program binaries separated from its data. All Windows app, for example, are located under `Program files`, but write their data either under user's `%APPDATA%` for personal data or `%ProgramData%` for shared data. You should follow this guidelines. If there are something that make you think different, please elaborates.

Comment: @SteveB if you make your command as answer i will mark it as answer

Comment: @ryadavilli it won't be contain user specific data

Comment: I would say ProgramData folder (as clarified by Steve B above) is the best location for your scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common conception (I would even say, a best practice) to have the program binaries separated from its data.

All Windows app, for example, are located under `Program files`, but write their data either under user's `%APPDATA%` for personal data or `%ProgramData%` for shared data. You **should** follow this guidelines, unless your program have very specific requirements.

Depending on the kind of data, especially if you want the user to find quickly the data, you can also create a subfolder under user's document folder.

Using C#, you will be able to find easily of this *special folders* using [Environment.GetFolderPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd783871.aspx). For example:

```
public string GetDataFolder()
{
    var appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, // Search under %APPDATA%
        Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create // Create the folder if it does not exists
    );
    var dataFolder = Path.Combine(
        appDataPath,
        "MyApplication"
    );
    return dataFolder;
}
```

If you look at the [Environment.SpecialFolderOption Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.specialfolderoption.aspx), you will see that most of the common places are easily be found.

As you stated the data will be shared by all users, you should specifically targets `%ProgramData%`, which is found by using `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` :

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users.

Ultimately, this folder will be resolved as (with default settings) `C:\Programdata\MyApplication`.